# What is Isaiah 29:4 describing when he says "deep from the earth you shall speak"?

Tags: isaiah

> [Isa 29:3-5 NLT] (3) I will be your enemy, surrounding Jerusalem and attacking its walls. I will build siege towers and destroy it. (4) **Then deep from the earth you will speak; from low in the dust your words will come. Your voice will whisper from the ground like a ghost conjured up from the grave.** (5) "But suddenly, your ruthless enemies will be crushed like the finest of dust. Your many attackers will be driven away like chaff before the wind. Suddenly, in an instant,

Answer (score 1):

Isaiah seems to be echoing Jeremiah to describe the abject ultimate abasement of Israel by the LORD through the hand of their enemies. The message being given is that Israel must endure their punishment patiently until it is over and God turns their fortunes:

> [Jer 16:2-4, 12-14, 16-19 CSB] (2) "Do not marry or have sons or daughters in this place. (3) "For this is what the LORD says concerning sons and daughters born in this place as well as concerning the mothers who bear them and the fathers who father them in this land: (4) "They will die from deadly diseases. They will not be mourned or buried but will be like manure on the soil's surface. They will be finished off by sword and famine. Their corpses will become food for the birds of the sky and for the wild animals of the land.  ... (12) "You did more evil than your fathers. Look, each one of you was following the stubbornness of his evil heart, not obeying me. (13) "So I will hurl you from this land into a land that you and your fathers are not familiar with. There you will worship other gods both day and night, for I will not grant you grace.'  (14) "However, look, the days are coming" ​-- ​the LORD's declaration ​-- ​"when it will no longer be said, 'As the LORD lives who brought the Israelites from the land of Egypt,' ... (16) "I am about to send for many fishermen" ​-- ​this is the LORD's declaration ​-- ​"and they will fish for them. Then I will send for many hunters, and they will hunt them down on every mountain and hill and out of the clefts of the rocks, (17) "for my gaze takes in all their ways. They are not concealed from me, and their iniquity is not hidden from my sight. (18) **"I will first repay them double for their iniquity and sin because they have polluted my land.** They have filled my inheritance with the carcasses of their abhorrent and detestable idols."  (19) LORD, my strength and my stronghold, my refuge in a time of distress, the nations will come to you from the ends of the earth, and they will say, "Our fathers inherited only lies, worthless idols of no benefit at all."
>
> [Lam 3:1-66 NLT] (1) I am the one who has seen the afflictions that come from the rod of the LORD's anger. (2) He has led me into darkness, shutting out all light. (3) He has turned his hand against me again and again, all day long. (4) He has made my skin and flesh grow old. He has broken my bones. (5) He has besieged and surrounded me with anguish and distress. **(6) He has buried me in a dark place, like those long dead.** (7) He has walled me in, and I cannot escape. He has bound me in heavy chains. (8) **And though I cry and shout, he has shut out my prayers.** (9) He has blocked my way with a high stone wall; he has made my road crooked. (10) He has hidden like a bear or a lion, waiting to attack me. (11) **He has dragged me off the path and torn me in pieces, leaving me helpless and devastated.** (12) He has drawn his bow and made me the target for his arrows. (13) He shot his arrows deep into my heart. (14) My own people laugh at me. All day long they sing their mocking songs. (15) He has filled me with bitterness and given me a bitter cup of sorrow to drink. (16) **He has made me chew on gravel. He has rolled me in the dust.** (17) Peace has been stripped away, and I have forgotten what prosperity is. (18) I cry out, "My splendor is gone! Everything I had hoped for from the LORD is lost!" (19) The thought of my suffering and homelessness is bitter beyond words. (20) I will never forget this awful time, as I grieve over my loss.
>
> (21) Yet I still dare to hope when I remember this: (22) The faithful love of the LORD never ends! His mercies never cease. (23) Great is his faithfulness; his mercies begin afresh each morning. (24) I say to myself, "The LORD is my inheritance; therefore, I will hope in him!" (25) The LORD is good to those who depend on him, to those who search for him. (26) So it is good to wait quietly for salvation from the LORD. (27) And it is good for people to submit at an early age to the yoke of his discipline: (28) **Let them sit alone in silence beneath the LORD's demands. (29) Let them lie face down in the dust, for there may be hope at last.** (30) Let them turn the other cheek to those who strike them and accept the insults of their enemies. (31) For no one is abandoned by the Lord forever. (32) Though he brings grief, he also shows compassion because of the greatness of his unfailing love. (33) For he does not enjoy hurting people or causing them sorrow. (34) If people crush underfoot all the prisoners of the land, (35) if they deprive others of their rights in defiance of the Most High, (36) if they twist justice in the courts--doesn't the Lord see all these things? (37) Who can command things to happen without the Lord's permission? (38) Does not the Most High send both calamity and good? (39) Then **why should we, mere humans, complain when we are punished for our sins?** (40) Instead, let us test and examine our ways. Let us turn back to the LORD. (41) Let us lift our hearts and hands to God in heaven and say, (42) **"We have sinned and rebelled, and you have not forgiven us. (43) "You have engulfed us with your anger, chased us down, and slaughtered us without mercy.** (44) You have hidden yourself in a cloud so **our prayers cannot reach you.** (45) **You have discarded us as refuse and garbage among the nations.** (46) "All our enemies have spoken out against us. (47) We are filled with fear, for we are trapped, devastated, and ruined." (48) Tears stream from my eyes because of the destruction of my people! (49) My tears flow endlessly; they will not stop (50) until the LORD looks down from heaven and sees. (51) **My heart is breaking over the fate of all the women of Jerusalem.** (52) My enemies, whom I have never harmed, **hunted me down like a bird. (53) They threw me into a pit and dropped stones on me.** (54) The water rose over my head, and I cried out, "This is the end!" (55) But **I called on your name, LORD, from deep within the pit**. (56) You heard me when I cried, "Listen to my pleading! Hear my cry for help!" (57) Yes, you came when I called; you told me, "Do not fear." (58) Lord, you are my lawyer! Plead my case! For you have redeemed my life. (59) You have seen the wrong they have done to me, LORD. Be my judge, and prove me right. (60) You have seen the vengeful plots my enemies have laid against me. (61) LORD, you have heard the vile names they call me. You know all about the plans they have made. (62) My enemies whisper and mutter as they plot against me all day long. (63) Look at them! Whether they sit or stand, I am the object of their mocking songs. (64) Pay them back, LORD, for all the evil they have done. (65) Give them hard and stubborn hearts, and then let your curse fall on them! (66) Chase them down in your anger, destroying them beneath the LORD's heavens.

Isaiah introduces the resurrection of Israel by a "double" because he is going to assure Israel that her sins have finally been paid for twice and calling for the ministry of John the baptizer and the arrival of the LORD in the person of the Messiah!:

> [Isa 40:1-5 NLT] (1) "**Comfort, comfort** my people," says your God. (2) "Speak tenderly **to Jerusalem**. **Tell her that her sad days are gone and her sins are pardoned. Yes, the LORD has punished her twice over for all her sins."** (3) Listen! It's the voice of someone shouting, "Clear the way through the wilderness for the LORD! Make a straight highway through the wasteland for our God! (4) Fill in the valleys, and level the mountains and hills. Straighten the curves, and smooth out the rough places. (5) Then the glory of the LORD will be revealed, and all people will see it together. The LORD has spoken!"

Since all scripture is ultimately about the Messiah and the messianic age (the first century) we can see in this a prophecy of the Messiah, dying on behalf of the Israel of God and raising her from the dead:

> [Jhn 2:19-21 KJV] (19) Jesus answered and said unto them, Destroy this temple, and in three days I will raise it up. (20) Then said the Jews, Forty and six years was this temple in building, and wilt thou rear it up in three days? (21) But he spake of the temple of his body.
>
> [NLT Lamentation 3]:
>   (14) My own people laugh at me. All day long they sing their mocking songs. (15) He has filled me with bitterness and given me a bitter cup of sorrow to drink. (16) He has made me chew on gravel. He has rolled me in the dust.
>
> [Jhn 18:11 KJV] (11) Then said Jesus unto Peter, Put up thy sword into the sheath: the cup which my Father hath given me, shall I not drink it?

Answer (score 0):

Great question. Grace and peace. Let your ears hear what the spirit says. The earth is your mortal body.

From what was man first made? The dust of the earth. Where is the Kingdom of God according to Christ? Within you.

You "enter in" to yourself, into the dust if the earth, up past the cherubim back into the garden...mentally reconcile that which is outside of you with that which is inside of you..(confess your sins) and wait. Lamentations: "it is good to wait quietly for the salvation of the Lord.". God is spirit. Our thoughts are electrical. Shut off the thoughts, (electrical energy...storm around "you") and "living water" aka Gods spirit rises up from within your mortal flesh.... and then your mortal flesh is quickened to give an answer to the enemies whether they are located within you or on the outside.

"Then deep from the earth you will speak; from low in the dust your words will come. Your voice will whisper from the ground like a ghost conjured up from the grave."

Shalom.

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

The things written in Isaiah (as well as all of the books of the Bible) are relevant still for today.

This speaks of His people today who have turned away from the Way of righteousness and have surrounded themselves with Bible teachers (who really have no knowledge) who preach the dead words of deceased  “wise” men  (who are supposed to be wise by many) who wrote many Bible commentaries in years past for the living to consult today.

The nations that surround us consider His people as the lowest in this world and speak evil of us.  We should be the head and not the tail in this world but because of iniquity inside the churches of men this is not so.

His people have no knowledge in this world currently as they have no understanding of the Scriptures.

The LORD has poured out upon us the “spirit of deep sleep” and have closed the eyes of our understanding as our leaders have no knowledge.   Those who are considered by many as “wise” and are considered knowledgeable of the Scriptures are not.  The eyes of their understanding of the Scriptures are covered by the LORD.

> Isaiah 29:10-14 KJV (10)  ***For the LORD hath poured out upon you the
>   spirit of deep sleep, and hath closed your eyes: the prophets and your
>   rulers, the seers hath he covered***. (11)  And the vision of all is
>   become unto you as the words of a book that is sealed, which men
>   deliver to one that is learned, saying, Read this, I pray thee: and he
>   saith, I cannot; for it is sealed: (12)  And the book is delivered to
>   him that is not learned, saying, Read this, I pray thee: and he saith,
>   I am not learned.

This has happened because His people draw near Him with their mouth and with their lips do they honor Him but they have removed their heart (all together) from Him .   Their heart goes after their covetousness instead.

Their fear of God is taught by the commandments of men.  People keep the commandments of men to show that they fear God but their worship of Him is in vain by doing so as they disregard the commandment to have love for one another in order to keep the commandments of men and judge others using them as a basis in doing so.

> (13)  ***Wherefore the Lord said, Forasmuch as this people draw near me
>   with their mouth, and with their lips do honour me, but have removed
>   their heart far from me, and their fear toward me is taught by the
>   precept of men:***

There is no understanding in the “wise men” of the churches today.   Their wisdom has perished.

The “wise” consult the words of dead men who have already perished from this earth and have left behind their many books…their many words….their many private interpretations of the Bible.... for the living to turn to today.

The sermons of many preachers today are from beyond the grave as many consult the many books of supposed “great”, "knowledgeable" men of God who have passed away many years ago.

> (14)  *Therefore, behold, I will proceed to do a marvellous work among
>   this people, even a marvellous work and a wonder: **for the wisdom of
>   their wise men shall perish, and the understanding of their prudent
>   men shall be hid**.*

Many use the private interpretations of dead men…..men who have died and have written many books … their  many Bible commentaries.   They have passed away many years ago and yet many of the living still consult their dead writings that contain no knowledge.

The Bible commentaries of dead men (who have totaled missed the point of Jesus bringing His eternal life for us in this world in the here-and-now) are not to be consulted and preached to the living in this earth.

They have perished without the eternal life of Jesus being made manifest in their mortal bodies and they no knowledge as they did not understand. Their perishing from off this earth shows us that they missed the point of Jesus coming into this world entirely.

Again, many use the Bible commentaries of dead men to preach their words of “knowledge” to His people who are living in this earth now.  But there is really no knowledge being preached in the use of their dead words.

**The one using a dead man’s Bible commentary today for preaching “knowledge” of the Scriptures (where there is really none) to the living  is one who has a “familiar spirit”…**   and  he is speaking out of the ground when the voice of the dead man’s (who is returned to the dust now and is buried in a grave somewhere deep in the earth) Bible commentary is being used .

The one preaching another dead man’s private interpretation of the Scriptures has a “familiar spirit” …being a “ventriloquist”….mumbling the dead, unknowledgeable words of a deceased guy who died in the 1800’s sometime (for example) or some other past time period.  The living preacher is not using his own voice (nor the Lord’s) but the voice of a dead man’s written Bible commentary.

> Isaiah 29:4 KJV (4)  **And thou shalt be brought down, and shalt speak
>   out of the ground, and thy speech shall be low out of the dust, and
>   thy voice shall be, as of one that hath a familiar spirit, out of the
>   ground, and thy speech shall whisper out of the dust.**

The dead Bible commentaries of dead men being used to preach supposed Bible “knowledge” to those who are living today in this earth is not to be done.

There is no knowledge in their private interpretations of the Bible.

Those who use them only “peep” …chirping as a bird without understanding….without meaningful words and  are only “ventriloquists”  because they are only voicing the “understanding” of the dead guy who wrote a Bible commentary based on his own private interpretation.   It sounds beautiful…as a bird chirping…but if you truly listen to them, there really is no understanding of their peeping. They are really stammering....mumbling without knowledge.

The “wizards” (meaning “to know”) today only “peep” as they use  beautiful-sounding but unknowledgeable words from beyond the grave in the empty words of the many books of now deceased ,supposed “wise men”  that have written  them and have left them behind for the living to consult.

Yet, the supposed “wise” are considered by many to be knowledgeable (“wizards” = “to know”)  and yet are really muttering  words that no one can truly understand.  The many books of deceased church “wise men” …their dead commentaries…..should not be consulted.

Those who suggest that the living consult the dead man’s dead writings have no light….no knowledge within them.

We should instead turn to the testimony of the living Jesus whose living words interpret the words of the apostles and prophets in the Spirit of Truth.  His testimony makes their words living.

> Isaiah 8:19-20 KJV (19)  *A**nd when they shall say unto you, Seek unto
>   them that have familiar spirits, and unto wizards that peep, and that
>   mutter: should not a people seek unto their God? for the living to the
>   dead? (20)  To the law and to the testimony: if they speak not
>   according to this word, it is because there is no light in them.***

We are not to regard those false teachers who preach the dead words…the dead, private interpretations/commentaries…of those who have passed away already.  The false teachers nor their use of the dead man’s teaching are not through the Spirit of Truth.

> Leviticus 19:31 KJV (31)  **Regard not them that have familiar spirits,
>   neither seek after wizards, to be defiled by them: I am the LORD your
>   God.**

Seeking after the authority of dead men’ s dead teachings and preaching them is “speaking out of the ground”…out of the dust….as one who has a “familiar spirit”…..